# MySQL Can Foreign Key Be Null

Tags: mysql

**Question**

Is it valid to have a Null foreign key? Are there any disadvantages?

**Example**

```
 ______        _________________
|  id  |      |   id    | id_fk |
|   1  |      |    1    |   2   |
|   2  |      |    2    |   5   |
|   3  |      |    3    |       |
|   4  |      |    4    |   1   |
|   5  |      |    5    |       |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾        ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Comment: Yes.  It is fine to do, assuming there is no relationship.

Comment: Yes, you can. Not every record must have a ref to another table

Comment: Yes. What fallacious experiment did you perform that led you to believe otherwise? And what are you asking? Whether it's possible, or what the best practice is, or the positive and negative points of doing so?

Comment: If it's possible and if it can generate future troubles, cause I was experiencing a lot of problems related to null foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and no it is not bad practice. You will want to make sure you take this into account when running queries on your database. If you attempt to run an inner join with your selects, then you will automatically exclude all rows with a null value. In cases where you want to join on that relationship even if the foreign key is null, you will want to use an outer join.